# I want my PC to boot in recovery mode by default

Tags: recovery-mode, headless

I have a headless 18.04 machine without screen, mouse and keyboard. I can't press keys to select the recovery mode and the machine won't show a working greeter in standard mode. So I want it to start in recovery mode by default without pressing any keys. I want it to boot like I pressed shift during booting, selected recovery and then continue in normal mode because this gives a working greeter

Comment: Being headless, does the machine normally boot into a full working Ubuntu? If so, what's the point of having it boot to recovery mode instead? If you've got a broken greeter, why not fix that?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have clarified the question. By default the machine boots into an empty purple screen and it does not respond to the mouse or keyboard.

Comment: If this machine DID fully boot normally, how would you use it headless?

Comment: Using NoMachine.

Comment: How do you get the IP for this headless machine? Did this problem occur before you installed NoMachine?

Comment: Yes, the problem was there before I installed NoMachine. I suspect that these effects are caused by an unsupported graphics card. This machine is an old HP Proliant Gen6 server. NoMachine gets the address for the machine. I can ping it using the machine name, ssh into it using the machine name and so on.

Comment: That's kind of where I was headed. What graphics card? What driver/version?

Comment: Thanks for your help. `lspci | grep VGA` sais `01:03.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] ES1000 (rev 02)`.

Comment: This HP server has a built-in video port, yes? Why not try removing the PCI card and connecting a display/mouse/keyboard to the internal ports? At least for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102551/discussion-between-tradingderivatives-eu-and-heynnema).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From chat...

HP Proliant Gen6 server, [Some docs here.](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/getdocument.aspx?docname=c04282582)

We finally got it to fully boot by using `nomodeset`.

We're now investigating video drivers for the AMD/ATI ES1000 rev 02.

**Update #1:**

The 10-year old ES1000 embedded video chip isn't supported anywhere that I can see. The best that we might be able to do is to run with `nomodeset` (it's a headless server)... or install another PCI video card.

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

Find the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Save the file and quit gedit.

Then do:

`sudo update-grub`

`reboot`

Comment: As agreed in the chat, I pressed shift during boot to get into this grub screen, then pressed 'e', added the nomodeset thing, continued boot, greeter appeared (that is something already!), logged in, Software and Updates, tab additional drivers, and there it sais after some time "No additional drivers available". So now I am looking for a graphics card driver all over the internet like suggested.

Comment: I searched for the drivers on the link you provided... but there is nothing like this `ES1000` available. More to follow tomorrow.

Comment: Using `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"` I get a greeter. Thanks a lot!